# When is and isn’t a Surjection ‘self evident.’

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

studying my first ever abstract maths course (how exciting), and one thing that often comes up is that when proving a surjection…sometimes it’s just given as ‘self evident,’ other times no matter how simple…we have to do some work to get marks. I want to understand where the line is, and get some pointers.

**’Self evident’ example**

For example: The surjective property of a map between a subgroup $H$ and a left Coset $aH$ is seen as self-evident.

Map $H \to aH, F(h) = ah$

“Take $x \in aH$, then $x = ah$, for some $h \in H$ by definition. So we have  $F(h) = x$ thus our map is surjective.”

*Question*: I appreciate this does seem obvious, but can anyone show me any subtle changes that might seem right, but would make this answer actually wrong. I.e. when the answer is so simple, I feel like even the smallest change would throw it off.

**Non self evident example**

$$F(x) = x^2 + 1$$

Here we actually have to find the inverse, so that we can show that always, $f(f^{-1}(x))$ gives us our desired $y$…I.e the ‘$x$’ that always exists such that $f(x) = y$ is $x = (y - 1)^{1/2}$

Then: $f(x) = f\left((y - 1)^{1/2}\right) = y$

[*Edit:* Has been kindly noted that this isn't even a valid surjection over the real numbers (which I feel like kind of speaks to my question)...]

$x^3 + 1$ should work...

*Question* this error speaks to another problem I have. Is there any systematic way of knowing when that 'taking the inverse' method will fail...apart from just spotting an error where the domain and range are not equal?

*Question* Can anybody suggest some maps where I might think oh this is ‘just self evident’ but actually I need to do some work?

*Question* In a way I find the ‘self evident’ ones harder, because you kind of don’t need to do anything, but you do need to do something…can anyone give me an exact structure of what I need to say **and why it works**, and as suggested before, what things not to say (that might seem right) but wouldn’t get credit, or are simply wrong!

Thanks for helping with all the questions, hope this isn’t too basic!

Comment: That non self evident example is not a surjection, at least in the real domain, because, for example, there exists no $x \in \mathbb R$  such that $f(x)= 0$. That is, there is no **real** $x$ such that $x = (-1)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Determining the range of a function can be very difficult. Therefore, it can be very difficult to determine whether in a given target set, the function is surjective.

Comment: Concerning the inverse of $x^2+1$ : The inverse only exists if we choose one branch , for example we demand $x\ge 0$. Then, we have a strictly increasing function we can invert and the inverse is $\sqrt{x-1}$ for $x\ge 1$. The range is here $[1,\infty[$

Comment: Something is "self-evident" if it is "self-evident" for you. Whether something is obvious is subjective. If you don't understand whether something is surjective, then you need an argument.

Comment: @Peter thank you very much for pointing this out! It actually perfectly highlighted another issue I have, and I suggested an alternate function which I believe is surjective?

Comment: @QiZhu thank you very much for your comment. This really speaks to my exact question. Because sometimes as stated the answer is just “by the definition of the map/function…it is surjective” but I just feel a bit uncomfortable with that….For example. My ‘self-evident one’ how would you prove it was surjective not the way I have currently stated?

Comment: Your argument is OK. But whenever you don't immediately see the surjectivity, you must give an argument, that was my point.

Comment: @QiZhu I completely agree. That argument was from the mark scheme/book. And there's a bunch like that, where it's kind of, not really an argument. If you have time would you mind providing an alternate proof for the 'self-evident' one? I tried but it just felt a bit like a dog chasing its tail.

Comment: Your proof is the one I would give as well. It is about writing out the definitions and understanding the definitions. These are perfectly fine arguments, but if you can't see that it is really an argument, then you need to give more details. If you're unsure of your argument, then you should try to understand which step makes you feel uneasy.

Comment: Pertaining self-evidence more fundamentally: I think a good rule of thumb as to when something is self-evident is when you can give a straightforward explanation in one simple sentence that is easy to understand if you have adequate background knowledge. I think it's good practice to then write that sentence down in a proof. If it's really obvious, it's only a small bit of information to write down, but for someone else that doesn't see the idea/connection immediately, that little clue can be an immense help and save some frustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you prove surjectivity (at least, this is probably the most accessible way):

> Let $y$ be an arbitrary element of the codomain of $f$. Prove that whatever $y$ is, there exists $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $y = f(x)$.

In your "self-evident case", $y$ is **by definition** of the form $a x$ for some $x \in H$.

That is, **whatever** $y$ is, there is **by the definition of a coset** some $x$ in $H$ such that $y = f(x)$.

The "self-evidentness" of this is because it **follows directly from the definition**.

Hence to present such a proof, all you need to do is show "from the definition of (whatever) it follows that $\forall y \in \operatorname{Cdm} (f): \exists x \in \operatorname{Dom} (f): y = f(x)$.

Hope this helps.

Your second example is NOT as it stands a surjection because the image set of $f$ is all real numbers greater than or equal to $1$. It is assumed, unless we are told to the contrary, that if $f$ is defined as a "real function", the codomain is taken to be the whole of the set of real numbers.

If of course you are in the complex plane, then $f$ is of course surjective -- but obviously not injective.

Comment: Thank you this is super helpful, I appreciate you breaking its own to basics and providing a template!

Answer (score 2):

Surjectivity can be defined in the following way:

> Let $X,Y$ be sets, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. We say that $f$ is surjective if $Y=f(X)$.

What this means is that $Y$, also called the *codomain*, is equal to the *range* (or *image*) of $f$. Now by definition we must have that $f(X)\subseteq Y$, and so to prove surjectivity you prove that $Y\subseteq f(X)$. To do this, prove that if $y\in Y$, then $y\in f(X)$, which *by definition* means that $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in X$. Now some times this is a really trivial matter, such as in your first example, when you already are given that $Y=f(X)$, and in other cases this is extremely non-trivial and requires hard work.

Comment: Thank you so much this was really helpful. I hadn't actually come across this definition before, but after some browsing, I see how it follows from the other standard definition! Thanks also for putting this into Latex.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that a function $f$ is self-evidently a surjection, when codomain **is defined to be the range of $f$**

For instance in your left coset example.

We define $aH := \{ah, h\in H\}$ and $F : H\to aH, h\mapsto ah$.

In other words if we denote $f_a : G\to G, g\mapsto ag$,
then we have just said : take $aH = f_a(H)$ and take $F : H\to aH$ to be the restriction of $f_A$ from $H$ to $aH$.

Then by definition, because $aH$ is the image of $H$ by $f_A$, $F$ is surjective.

If you are not in this specific instance, you need a proof.

Comment: Super super helpful @justt, thank you. Am processing! Interesting that you increased the strength of the self evidence to a injection as well as surjection.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong: "a function f is self-evidently a bijection, when codomain is defined to be the range of f". No, take the example given: $y = x^2 + 1$. Yes, limiting the codomain to $\{y \in \mathbb R: y \ge 1\}$ does make it surjective, but if $x$ ranges over all $\mathbb R$ then $f$ is very clearly and obviously not injective.

Comment: If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is surjective, the range of $f$ must always be $B$ (otherwise $f$ is not surjective). So, according to your answer , every surjectivity is self-evident.

Comment: @Justt Okay so correct me if I’m the wrong. Can I describe what you are saying like this? 

Because the Function H —> aH where H is domain and aH is the codomain, is given by f(h) = ah, where ah is the range. For any h object of aH, I.e. aH = ah, the codomain and the range are the exact same? 

…I think this last line is wrong, don’t think I can really say aH = ah…I’m just trying to simplify it for myself.

Comment: @Peter It can be stated as a theorem: "The restriction of a mapping to its image set is a surjection" whose proof is trivial.

Comment: @CormJack One of the standard definitions of a surjection is that its image set (what you are calling "range") is equal to its codomain. The term "range" is ambiguous. Some sources use it to mean the codomain, some use it to mean the image set: $\{y: \exists x \in \operatorname{Dom} (f): y = f(x)\}$

Comment: @PrimeMover does justt response still work for surjectivity?

Comment: @CormJack: "increased the strength of the self evidence to a injection as well as surjection" NO -- injectivity is NOT required, and in fact the statement made at the top of this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @CormJack Read the comments, specifically those of Peter and myself.

Comment: We will always have to determine the range and compare it with the codomain. So finally we have that the surjectivity is self-evident if it is trivial to determine the range.

Comment: If $A$ is given , then the range of $f$ is determined as well (it is not ambigous) : It is the set of all possible outputs. "Image" is just another possible terminology for "range". It is the codomain that can be a proper superset of the range.

Comment: My apologies to all especially OP, I meant surjection, not bijection.